# Organizing enumerations in Scala

Tags: scala, enumeration

sorry for the long winded question:

Say I have a list of animals and I want to split them up like so:

```
BasicAnimal = {Cat, Dog}
Carnivore = {Cat, Dog, Dragon}
Herbivore = {Cat, Dog, Horse}
```

Now, these animals also have to live somewhere. So there's a

```
BasicShelter with a method shelter(animal: BasicAnimal)
Den with a method shelter(animal: Carnivore)
Shed with a method shelter(animal: Herbivore)
```

What's the best way to implement this in Scala? One attempt was:

```
class BasicAnimal extends Enumeration{
   val Cat, Dog = Value
}
class Carnivore extends BasicAnimal{
   val Dragon = Value
}
class Herbivore extends BasicAnimal{
   val Horse = Value
}
```

and then

```
class BasicHouse{
  def shelter(animal: BasicAnimal) = {//lots of code}
}
class Den{
  def shelter(animal: Carnivore) = {
  //again lots of code, but the cases dealing with Cat and Dog can be relegated to super.shelter
  }
}
class Shed{
  //the same
}
```

Sadly, this won't work. The Dog from Carnivore is different from the Dog in BasicAnimal. That is Carnivore.Dog == BasicAnimal.Dog returns false, so, the only way to reuse the code from BasicHouse in Den is by having a rather hacky equality method that compares the strings of the enums (or something similar). It works, but it's very unclean. Can you see any other possibilities?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As per @paradigmatic's answer, but with a few enhancements:

```
sealed abstract trait BasicAnimal
sealed abstract trait Carnivore extends BasicAnimal
sealed abstract trait Herbivore extends BasicAnimal
sealed abstract trait Omnivore extends Carnivore with Herbivore

case object Dog extends Omnivore
case object Cat extends Omnivore
case object Dragon extends Carnivore
case object Horse extends Herbivore
```

Making the traits abstract allows you to take advantage of completeness checking in pattern matches (which would otherwise warn that a match on the trait itself wasn't attempted)

The `Omnivore` traits removes some duplication, and also helps with pattern matching

Using `extends` instead of self typing is just plain cleaner, and more intuitive

`case object` instead of `object` is mostly done to better document the intent of the code, and also to provide a sane implementation of `toString`

Answer (score 5):

An alternative solution to enumeration is to use `sealed trait` to define enumerations.

With your example:

```
sealed trait BasicAnimal
sealed trait Carnivore { self: BasicAnimal => }
sealed trait Herbivore { self: BasicAnimal => }

object Dog extends BasicAnimal with Carnivore with Herbivore
object Cat extends BasicAnimal with Carnivore with Herbivore
object Dragon extends BasicAnimal with Carnivore
object Horse extends BasicAnimal with Herbivore
```

That is more flexible than Enumeration, but you lose the possibility of easily enumerating all values.

Comment: `Carnivore/Herbivore extends BasicAnimal` would simplify the definitions a bit. Is there a reason to prefer the self-types?

Comment: Not in that example, you are right. But if the traits start bearing methods, it may be useful.

Comment: Interesting... If BasicAnimal is sealed, does that mean that I can iterate over all the animals that are considered basic animals? Enumerations would allow me to do this and, in my case anyway, I iterate over all the possible values in at least a couple of places.

Comment: Also, what does self: BasicAnimal do? I can't find any material on it, all I can see are people defining the "this" keyword.

Comment: @Henry Henrinson: "If `BasicAnimal` is sealed, does that mean that I can iterate over all the animals that are considered basic animals?" Unfortunately not. It just means that all traits/classes which extend `BasicAnimal` are defined in this file. See http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9780596155957/ApplicationDesign.html#SelfTypeAnnotationsAndAbstractTypeMembers for an explanation of self-types.

Comment: @paradigmatic Still, could you give an example?

Comment: @Alexey Cheers for the link. I thought enumerating would be possible for a sealed type because of the support the compiler offers (i.e. it can check that a pattern-match has covered all possible cases. Then, it's not impossible to imagine that it could also iterate over all these types.)